# Saving a dictionary to a file

Tags: json, python-2.7, file, dictionary

I am pretty new to Python, I am trying to take contents of my dictionary called `python_diction`(which is located in a larger file) and save that data to a new a new file called `python_diction_saved.json`. I feel like I am pretty close the error I am currently receiving is `python_diction_saved.json` is not defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import json
f = open("python_diction.txt","w")
python_diction = {}
python_diction["items"] = []
python_diction["items"].append({"hello":1,"hi":2})
python_diction["items"].append({"hello":42,"hi":65})
python_diction["numbers"] = [1,2,3,5,7,8]
f.write(json.dumps(python_diction_saved.json))
f.close()
```

Comment: `python_diction_saved` => `python_diction`

Comment: Great, that solved the first traceback error, but now I am getting another traceback error......f.write(json.dumps(python_diction_saved.json))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'

Comment: come on: `python_diction_saved.json` => `python_diction`

Comment: You also need to open another file named `"python_diction_saved.json"`

Comment: @Faibbus no, the file is already open under `"python_diction.txt"`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : " and save that data to a new a new file called python_diction_saved.json"

Comment: oh this is bad :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to write your `python_diction` to a file named `python_diction_saved.json`, you can use `json.dump` (to avoid having to write it yourself):

```
import json
python_diction = {}
python_diction["items"] = []
python_diction["items"].append({"hello":1,"hi":2})
python_diction["items"].append({"hello":42,"hi":65})
python_diction["numbers"] = [1,2,3,5,7,8]

with open("python_diction_saved.json") as output_file:
    json.dump(python_diction, output_file)
```